# Spring Cloud Stream: Global errorChannel does not work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, messaging, spring-cloud-stream

According to this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-overview-introducing), it should be possible to subscribe to global error channel provided by Spring Integration - "errorChannel".

In my very simple case it does not work:

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding({MySink.class})
public class LoggingConsumerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoggingConsumerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(target = MySink.INPUT_ONE)
    public void handle(Person person) {
        System.out.println("Received: " + person);

        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(person.getName())){
            throw new RuntimeException("Wrong person name!");
        }
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mySink.mySink-group.errors")
    public void error(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println("Handling ERROR: " + message);
    }


    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public void errorGlobal(ErrorMessage message) {
        System.out.println("Handling ERROR GLOBAL SA: " + message);
    }

    @StreamListener("errorChannel")
    public void errorGlobalListener(ErrorMessage message) {
        System.out.println("Handling ERROR GLOBAL Listener: " + message);
    }

    public static class Person {
        private String name;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

MySink

```
public interface MySink {

    /**
     * Input channel name.
     */
    String INPUT_ONE = "inputOne";

    /**
     * @return input channel.
     */
    @Input(MySink.INPUT_ONE)
    SubscribableChannel inputOne();
}
```

properties

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=192.168.0.100
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputOne.destination=mySink
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputOne.group=mySink-group
```

The destination-specific handler works (mySink.mySink-group.errors), but two other handlers never get called.

What is wrong here?

Tried with Spring Boot 2.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong and it is working as expected. From the doc: *"The handle(..) method, which subscribes to the channel named input, throws an exception. Given there is also a subscriber to the error channel input.myGroup.errors all error messages are handled by this subscriber."* So, what this means is that your error is handled by either binding specific error handler (`mySink.mySink-group.errors`) or global (`errorChannel`).

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-error-handling

Comment: Thanks! Did not get the point that global and specific handlers do not work together by default.

Comment: That's fine, we'll try to update the docs to make it a bit more clear